# Check if Windows Authentication user has correct privilege in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

One of the users in our network needs access to one table of a `sql server database`. Since it's `Windows Authentication`, I created the user in `Security\Logins` and I've added the user in `Security\Users` for the database. I've also added the permissions.

Now I'd like to test it. How can I do this if I don't have this user's password? Obviously, he's not going to give it to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Execute As User = 'domain\Name';
-- Perform the test - use a Transaction if you need to test data modifications
Select * From schema.table;
Revert
```